# Sorting tableView data by timestamp with firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I'm looking to sort the data / arrays in my tableView by which date it was created. I don't have any code to support this but I have the code for the cells and images from the database.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Projects").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
            {
                let project = Project(dictionary: dictionary)
                self.ProjectsArray.append(project)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("fucked ")
            }
            self.FilterdProjectsArray = self.ProjectsArray
        }, withCancel: nil)
```

Database

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one line:

```
self.ProjectsArray.append(project)
self.ProjectsArray = self.ProjectsArray.sorted { (lhs, rhs) in lhs.timestamp < timestamp }
```

where `date` is the name of the date property on your `Project` object

#### Update

You could extend `Optional` to conform to `Comparable`, but a simpler way to handle it might be:

```
self.ProjectsArray = self.ProjectsArray.sorted { (lhs, rhs) in
    let lTimestamp = lhs.timestamp ?? NSNumber(integerLiteral: 0)
    let rTimestamp = rhs.timestamp ?? NSNumber(integerLiteral: 0)
    return lTimestamp < rTimestamp
}
```

#### Update 2

Turns out that NSNumbers aren't comparable. Looks like you'll need to use `Int` or `Double`, whichever makes more sense for your data (are you using whole or floating-point numbers?

```
self.ProjectsArray = self.ProjectsArray.sorted { (lhs: Project, rhs: Project) in
    let lTimestamp: Int
    if let lNum = lhs.timestamp {
      lTimestamp = Int(lNum)
    } else {
      lTimestamp = 0
    }

    let rTimestamp: Int
    if let rNum = rhs.timestamp {
      rTimestamp = Int(rNum)
    } else {
      rTimestamp = 0
    }
    return lTimestamp < rTimestamp
}
```

Comment: I use a timestamp, everything should be working if I either convert the timestamp to a date or I just sort it from the timestamp itself. Unfortunately I don't know how to do either...

Comment: What is the type of the timestamp? String?

Comment: NSNumber but I can convert to string?

Comment: Whats best, String or NSNumber?

Comment: NSNumber is fine. Since NSNumber is comparable the code above should just work, assuming your date property is called `date`.

Comment: It's actually project.timestamp. How do I convert it? Xcode gives me a error when I replace the "date" with project.timestamp

Comment: How about `self.ProjectsArray.sorted { (lhs, rhs) in lhs.timestamp < rhs.timestamp }`?

Comment: When tried Xcode: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber?' operands

Comment: Sounds like you need a way to compare two optional NSNumbers. Check the edit above.

Comment: Same problem... maybe if let... to remove the optional?

Comment: Yeah, you've got the right idea. Check the update above.

Comment: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber' operands on the return line. I have no idea this time...

Comment: I get this message at the "in" part: 'NSNumber?' is not convertible to 'Project'. I will make your answer green or whatever as thanks for all your work. Tell me if you find a solution.

Comment: Whoops, forgot that the elements being compared are projects and not timestamps. Updated.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!